# iPad on iOS 6 "UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device."

Tags: ipad, ios6

I'm explicitly executing the following line of code targeted for an iPad:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

which is giving me a runtime warning in my console (as indicated in the title).  While I can workaround this by specifying a different style, I don't completely understand why this would not be supported.  For example, if you place the MPMoviePlayerController in fullscreen, you can clearly see a translucent status bar.

In my case, I'm placing a view in fullscreen and also want the status bar to be translucent.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that error is telling you that the iPad does not support that status bar style.

From Documentation:

> On iPad devices, the UIStatusBarStyleDefault and
>   UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent styles default to the
>   UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque appearance.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the the documentation but wanted to see if this capability was possible through other ways.  As mentioned in the question, Apple clearly does provide this capability via the MPMoviePlayerController.  In iOS 7, it's a different story - you simply provide your own background as the status does not have one.

Comment: @zinc1oxide I don't think there is any way to achieve that status bar type.